# YouTube modal static

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, youtube

We have a page with a YouTube video modal, but get the following error when clicking on the video:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> ({bfd8100b-7a47-4b28-9e6d-e26f4a7d9ed9}_ytplayer001.js:747)
at HTMLAnchorElement.handle (jquery.tools.min.js:75)
at HTMLAnchorElement.o (jquery.tools.min.js:69)
```

The video modal pops up like it should, but shows a "snowy" screen and the video player controllers are non-responsive. I thought it might be related to a conflict issue and changed

}(jQuery));

to

}(jQuery.noConflict()));

but the problem still exists. I'm thinking I'm missing something very obvious, but after several days of troubleshooting, still can't figure it out.

UPDATE - When I remove the jquery.tools.min.js file, the video plays, but the form validation quits working. So there's something about that jquery.tools.min.js file that's clashing with the YouTube videos.

UPDATE - Replacing the jquery.tools.min.js with the current version fixed the issue with the video and form validation. All that remains is figuring out why the close button on the video modal is not working. When opening the video modal, the following error appears:

```
TypeError: $(...).on is not a function
$('.vid-close').on('click', function () {
```

Comment: Is there any chance you can make a sample page that has just this code in it so we can target the problem without looking at all the spurious other code?

Comment: It seems that in your code you use same ids multiple times(ex: `video-component, featuredMedia` etc). Don't do that. Ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.vid-close', function () {
   $('#vidlightbox').hide();
    if (videosource == "youtube") {
        $('#vidcontent').empty();
        att.entbus.ytPlayer.stopAll();
    } else {
        if (jwplayer('jwPlayer') != null) {
            try {
            jwplayer('jwPlayer').remove();
            } catch(err) {}
        }
    }
});
```

To this:

```
$('.vid-close').on('click', function () {
   $('#vidlightbox').hide();
    if (videosource == "youtube") {
        $('#vidcontent').empty();
        att.entbus.ytPlayer.stopAll();
    } else {
        if (jwplayer('jwPlayer') != null) {
            try {
            jwplayer('jwPlayer').remove();
            } catch(err) {}
        }
    }
});
```